# Passing ngfor index on click event

Tags: html, angular

So I have this ngfor and I wanna pass its index to a method (selectGateway) on click event. But it always just passes zero.

However when I use interpolation to display the index it shows all the correct indexes for all elements.

I tried "let i=index" and "index as i" Same result.

Using Angular 5. What am I doing wrong?

```
<div id="depcity{{i}}" *ngFor="let item of filteredGatewayList; let i = index" (click)="selectGateway(i)">
  <span class="fa fa-map-marker"></span>  <span>{{i}}{{item.gateway_name}}</span>
</div>
```

selectGateway(ind:any) {

```
alert("ind = "+ind);

this.filteredDestinationList = [];
if(ind == -1){
    this.gatewayInput = this.filteredGatewayList[this.selectedGatewayIndex]['gateway_name'];
    this.gatewayListHidden = true;
    this.selectedGatewayIndex = ind;
    this.filteredDestinationList = this.filteredGatewayList[this.selectedGatewayIndex];
    this.destinationInput = '';
}else{
    this.gatewayInput = this.filteredGatewayList[ind]['gateway_name'];
    this.gatewayListHidden = true;
    this.selectedGatewayIndex = ind;
    this.filteredDestinationList = this.filteredGatewayList[this.selectedGatewayIndex];
    this.destinationInput = '';
}
this.hideClearDepCity = false;
```

}

Comment: post `selectGateway` function

Comment: do you have a variable `i` declared somewhere else perhaps?

Comment: Added selectGateway function

Comment: @Cabman, as per your code it should be working fine,now we can only debug if we can see running code, try to create sample on stackblitz as I have created demo.

Answer (score 4):

**Snippet for pass index :**

```
<div *ngFor='let item of items;let i = index' (click)='getIndex(i)'>
```

**[WORKING DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngfor-click-index)**

Comment: Yes I have that, but it doesn't work
Here's my code

<div id="depcity{{i}}" *ngFor="let item of filteredGatewayList; index as i" (click)="selectGateway(i)"><span class="fa fa-map-marker"></span>  <span>{{i}}{{item.gateway_name}}{{i}}</span></div>

Comment: Update your question to include all of the relevant code. If you dont post all the code involved here how are we supposed to help you?

Comment: Added selectGateway function

Answer (score 0):

OK solved. Problem was I was also using the i variable somewhere else.